# How does the margin collapsing of parent and first/last child work?

Tags: html, css

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) says:

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or *clearance* to separate the `margin-top` of a block with the `margin-top` of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, *height*, *min-height*, or *max-height* to separate the `margin-bottom` of a block with the `margin-bottom` of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

I don't understand the last sentence. Why does the collapsed margin end up **outside the parent**? If it ends up outside the parent, where will it go? I have searched the web and read several tutorials about margin collapsing, but I didn't find anything about this.

Comment: "outside the parent" means that it will be rendered as if it is the parent's vertical margins, i.e. the first/last child block will not extend/stretch the dimensions of its containing parent using its assigned vertical margins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I threw together this little demo to help demonstrate the way this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pq8bm0o/

As you can see, I've made three elements, all nested within each other. The 2 inner containers both have a top margin value of `20px`, and the outermost container has a top border (one of the things that is considered a margin separator).

#### So what does this mean?

Because there is no separation at the top of the two child elements, there is only `20px` of space in between the outermost container and BOTH of the two child elements... the inner-most child has had it's margin collapse. Conversely, that margin that is there exists within the outermost container simply because of that border.. if you remove the border, all three elements will share the same `20px` of margin which will be outside of all three containers.

#### So why is it like this?

The best way to think about margin collapsing is like this:
Asking for a margin on an element will ensure that it has that much margin at it's top, and nothing more (unless it's forced to have more).. So looking at my example, Does the middle `.parent` element have `20px` of space above it? Yes, it does. Does the innermost child `.child` have `20px` of space above it? Yes, it also does... so the margin rule is being applied correctly. **It doesn't matter where that space lives, as long as it is there.**

Imagine that there was a border around the `.parent` element, but the margin was still displayed the way it is without, and then ask those same questions.. Does the `.parent` element have the space? Yes, but does the `.child` element? No, it no longer would, because there would not be `20px` of space in between it and the border that is now sitting above it... So, in reality, the space does not collapse, so that both of those questions can be answered as a "yes".

I hope that helps.. it's a little less of a direct answer to your question, and more of the theory behind how it works, so to put things a bit more plainly:

#### tl;dr

Margin, unlike padding, is meant to add space outside of elements. Because of this, margin will always collapse to the highest parent element whenever possible, to ensure that space is always "outside". Because it is outside of the element, it can count towards multiple different elements, as they all share that "outside" space.

Comment: I believed that an element consists of margin, border, padding and content so margin is always part of an element. But when margin collapsing happens, margins are shared between boxes, so margin isn't part of any particular element. Am I right?

Comment: In a sense.. Though margin does technically belong to that element, and in the case of a collapse, it's more just that both elements have unique margins that are just overlaid on top of each other. It's sort of just the way that you look at it in this case though I guess.